# Installing pywin32 - win32api.pyd permission denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, rpy2

I need to use win32api for rpy2. So I went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32 and tried to install it with pip. However, I have got the errors below. How can I overcome this permission denied problem?

---

```
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 07/09/15 16:48:30
Unpacking c:\users\myname\downloads\pywin32-219-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

Installing collected packages: pywin32

  Found existing installation: pywin32 218.4

    Uninstalling pywin32:

      Removing file or directory c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pywin32-218.4-py2.7.egg-info
      Successfully uninstalled pywin32

  Rolling back uninstall of pywin32

  Replacing c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pywin32-218.4-py2.7.egg-info
Cleaning up...

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 241, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1298, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 595, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 815, in move_wheel_files
move_wheel_files(self.name, self.req, wheeldir, user=self.use_user_site, home=self.target_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 172, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 166, in clobber
shutil.move(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 301, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\win32api.pyd'
```

Comment: Reason I tried to reinstall pywin32 is that, before this I went to python CLI and tried to "import win32api", but it said "Imoort Error: no module named win32api"

Comment: Probably you need to upgrade pip. What is the `pip --version` output?

Comment: pip 1.4.1 ....necessary?

Comment: The latest pip is 7.1.0.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#upgrade-pip

Comment: I got a similar Access is denied win32api.pyd with vanilla Python with pip 8.1.2

Answer (score -3):

If it's only a "permission denied" situation, try adding `sudo` before `pip` (Note: must be @ owner/administrator level)

Comment: @alfonso.kim Oh weird, I have linux and had the same problem but overcame it with sudo 0_o plz elaborate, I'm curious

Comment: sorry, I meant Windows. `sudo` does not work in Windows.

Comment: oh he/she's doing all this on windows, aiight my bad